# QTimer - Repetitive Timer

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I'm trying to have an QTimer object count in intervals, continuously to call a function. I followed an example and I have set the intervals but it doesn't appear to start counting ever again.

This is the piece of code I'm working with

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setInterval(1000);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(MyFunction()));
timer->start();
```

Comment: The code looks correct, could `MyFunction()` be blocking?

Comment: Are you sure you don't delete `timer` somewhere in your code? Is `MyFunction` called even once? Probably you need to show more code.

Comment: i think it may be going out of scope, I have it placed in a constructor. I'm not deleting it explicitly.

Comment: @rreeves You declared it on the heap, it can't go out of scope.  Just making sure: You have called `QApplication::exec()` in your `main(..)` function?

Comment: sorry didn't have the function set to a slot in the header file that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry didn't have the function set to a slot in the header file that was the problem

```
private slot:
void MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your main loop stil running?
Does the object you reference with "this" is stil existent?
Could you check if the timer is set to single shot?